React Navigation Header gets pushed up with KeyboardAvoidingView
I am using KeyboardAvoidingView at the top level of my app.  On Android, when I press into a text input & the keyboard opens, the React Navigation Header gets pushed up.  On iOS it's OK.

<KeyboardAvoidingView
    behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
>
    {children}
</KeyboardAvoidingView>

and a Scrollable Form component, with a sticky bottom save button:
return (
        <KeyboardAvoidingView
            keyboardVerticalOffset={headerHeight}
            style={[styles.safeArea, containerStyle]}
        >
            <ScrollView
                contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollView}
                contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior={'always'}
                {...scrollViewProps}
            >
                {renderMiddle?.()}
            </ScrollView>
            <Animated.View
                {...footerViewProps}
                style={[styles.footer, footerViewProps?.style]}
            >
                {renderFooter?.()}
            </Animated.View>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
};

Interestingly, if I blur & then refocus, the Header is fine.
Why is this?

Did you use SafeAreaViewcan you provide a full sample?

originally SafeAreaView was in place of KeyboardAvoidingView, but adding both don't seem to help.  This snippet above is the full sample of code - there's no other components, except for NavStack code
